# Randomly selecting a value from a dictionary AFTER a key was randomly selected

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a wheel of fortune type game in python. I have code that randomly selects a key from a dictionary but am not sure how to then select a random value from THAT specific key.

```
categories = {'Sayings': ['Actions speak louder than words', 'A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush',
                      'All good things come to an end', 'Among the blind the one eyed man is king',
                      'Fortune favors the bold', 'Ignorance is bliss'],'70s Soul Musicians': ['James Brown', 'Sly Stone', 'Aretha Franklin', 'Earth Wind & Fire', 'Stevie Wonder',
                        'Chaka Khan']}
```

## Program chooses a random key/category to have the player guess.

```
randCategory = str(random.choice(list(categories)))
print(randCategory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
import random

categories = {
    'Sayings': [
        'Actions speak louder than words',
        'A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush',
        'All good things come to an end',
        'Among the blind the one eyed man is king',
        'Fortune favors the bold',
        'Ignorance is bliss'
    ],
    '70s Soul Musicians': [
        'James Brown',
        'Sly Stone',
        'Aretha Franklin',
        'Earth Wind & Fire',
        'Stevie Wonder','Chaka Khan'
    ]
}

randCategory = str(random.choice(list(categories)))
randValue = str(random.choice(list(categories[randCategory])))

print(randCategory)
print(randValue)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is the use of square brackets inside relative to parentheses because of the key/value bracket/parentheses relationship?

Comment: categories is a named array with string elements array

Comment: randCategory gets a random key from the named array, randValue gets a random element from the sub array of `categories[randCategory]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `random.choice` on `categories[randCategory]` (and there's no need to cast the result of `random.choice` to  `str`):

```
randCategory = random.choice(list(categories))
print(randCategory)
randValue = random.choice(categories[randCategory])
print(randValue)
```

Output (random):

```
70s Soul Musicians
Earth Wind & Fire
```